# Perform the same action on multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have this line:

```
$("#clients-edit-wrapper").height($(window).height()-150);
```

I would like to apply that height function to more than just that specific ID in one line of jQuery. Is there a way to chain elements together and apply that height function once for multiple elements? Basically, I want to apply that height function to 3 or 4 other DIVs but I would rather not have 3 or 4 more lines of jQuery to accomplish this.

Is this possible?

---

**Answer from VisioN below (shows how much of a jQuery newbie I am!):**

You can use either multiple selector:

```
$("#clients-edit-wrapper, #div2, #div3").height($(window).height() - 150);
```

Or class selector (which is certainly better!):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="clients-edit-wrapper" class="myClass"></div>
<div id="div2" class="myClass"></div>
<div id="div3" class="myClass"></div>

// JavaScript
$(".myClass").height($(window).height() - 150);
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#clients-edit-wrapper, #div2, #div3").height($(window).height() - 150);
```

Or [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (*which is certainly better!*):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="clients-edit-wrapper" class="myClass"></div>
<div id="div2" class="myClass"></div>
<div id="div3" class="myClass"></div>

// JavaScript
$(".myClass").height($(window).height() - 150);
```

Comment: Nice! Shows how much of a newbie I am :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comma `,` to separate selectors.

```
$('#div1, #div2, div3').height($(window).height()-150);
```

If it were me though, I'd just set a class on them.